# Python multithreading producing funky results

Tags: python, multithreading, time

I'm fairly new to multithreading in Python and encountered an issue (likely due to concurrency problems). When I run the code below, it produces "normal" 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 digits for the first 9 numbers. However, when it moves on to the next batch of numbers (the ones that should be printed by each thread after it "sleeps" for 2 seconds) it spits out:

- different numbers each time
- often very large numbers
- sometimes no numbers at all

I'm guessing this is a concurrency issue where by the time each original thread got to printing the second number after "sleep" the i variable has been tampered with by the code, but can someone please explain what exactly is happening step-by-step and why the no numbers/large numbers phenomenon?

```
import threading
import time

def foo(text):
    print(text)
    time.sleep(2)
    print(text)

for i in range(1,10):
    allTreads = []
    current_thread = threading.Thread(target = foo, args= (i,))
    allTreads.append(current_thread)
    current_thread.start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your problem is called race condition. Sometimes when the code is executed, one thread will print a number before the implicit '\n' of another thread, and that's why you often see those kind of behaviours.

Also, whats the purpose of the `allTreads` list there? It is restarted at every iteration, so it stores the `current_thread` and then is deleted at the end of the current iteration.

In order to avoid race conditions, you need some kind of synchronization between threads. Consider the `threading.Lock()`, in order to avoid that more than one thread at a time prints the given text:

```
import threading
import time


lock = threading.Lock()

def foo(text):
    with lock:
        print(text)
    time.sleep(2)

    with lock:
        print(text)

for i in range(1,10):
    allTreads = []
    current_thread = threading.Thread(target = foo, args= (i,))
    allTreads.append(current_thread)
    current_thread.start()
```

The threading documentation in python is quite good. I recommend you to read these two links:

[Python Threading Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html)

[Real Python Threading](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/)

Comment: Got it, thank you! Will check out those resources.

The allTreads list is based on the code here: https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/chapter17/